# How Can I Get Some Sponge In Minecraft Without Command Blocks or Under Water Temples And Without Mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If You Can Help me Find That I Could Really Give You Credit

Comment: In the creative inventory..?

Comment: @ben I think he means survival.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sponge says everything here!

Answer (score 1):

Without cheats/external tools, in vanilla survival Minecraft, sponges can *only* be found in water temples. If you want sponges, you are going to have to explore and conquer a water temple.

If you're in creative mode, you can find sponges by clicking on the compass, and searching for "sponge". They are available in the creative inventory.

Comment: To be more specific, they are in the building blocks page (the first one), about halfway down